# django model form saving data to multiple models

Tags: python, django

I have a Custom User model with a team field.  I also have a Team model with a ManyToManyField for the Custom Users.

I have a template that allows a user to create a team using whatever Team Name they want.  Upon creation, I want that user's Team to be assigned but the team primary key isn't created until the Team is created so how do I get that primary key id into the Custom User model?

My direction of thought is that I would perform a user save after the "create-team" form save in the views, but I'm not sure how to do that.

**models.py**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False, default='YourTeam')
    team_type = models.CharField(choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES, default='Free', max_length=30)
    num_users = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    emails = models.ManyToManyField('CustomUser', related_name='teamemails')

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, verbose_name='first name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, verbose_name='last name')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='userteam')
    team_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team_name = forms.CharField(label='Team Name', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['team_name']
```

**views.py**

```
@verified_email_required
def create_team(request):
    template = 'users/create_team.html'

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateTeamForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.team_name = request.team_name
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Team Created!')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Oops! Something went wrong')

    else:

        form = CreateTeamForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I believe team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='userteam') is an unnecessary field in CustomUser model, and  use a proper  filed name for emails = models.ManyToManyField('CustomUser', related_name='teamemails'). Create the Team creation template like , can create with out users, add another template where the user can assign 'custom users' to Team

Comment: Thank you for your help @Jisson - it helped me solve the problem and clean up my project.